# Error trying to cast view to wrapper class using view.GetChildAt

Tags: android

I'm trying to return a wrapper class when using View.GetChildAt but it is giving me an IllegalCastException. I know that the child that I'm trying to return is an EditText

```
MyEditText firstName = (MyEditText)infoLayout.GetChildAt(3);
```

Note: I cannot use FindByID in this case.

I'm guessing that it has something to do with trying to convert a base class into a derived class, but I'm hoping that there is a workaround.

Here is my xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
<TextView
    android:text="Type"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1"
    android:id="@+id/sp_type"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />
<TextView
    android:text="First Name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textView1" />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView2"
    android:id="@+id/et_firstName"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If it is not of Type `MyEditText`, why typecast it?

Comment: What class does it say it is? Can you post your layout?

Comment: It is an EditText class that GetChildAt returns. I want to use MyEditText class which is a wrapper for some extra functionality that I need.

Comment: Got it. I had to change EditText in xml to my wrapper class

`<com.Android.Util.MyEditText
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView2"
    android:id="@+id/et_firstName"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />`

I also had to add the EditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) constructor to my wrapper class